# Scipy minimize: How to pass args to both the objective and the constraint

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy

My MWE is as follows

```
def obj(e, p):
    S = f(e) + g(p)
    return S
```

I would like to minimize this function over only `e` and pass `p` as an argument to the function. However, I also would like a constraint that depends on `p` and `e` that is of the form `p + e < 1`

I tried

```
cons = {'type': 'ineq',
       'fun': lambda e, p: -e -p + 1,
       'args': (p)}
```

And then, I try to minimize this for the case of `p = 0.5`

```
minimize(obj, initial_guess, method = 'SLSQP', args = 0.5, constraints = cons)
```

but this doesn't work. I get the error `name 'p' is not defined` in the line where I define `cons`. How do I pass the argument `p` to both the objective function and the constraint?

---

Full code below

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.stats import entropy
import numpy as np

#Create a probability vector
def p_vector(x):
    v = np.array([x, 1-x])
    return v


#Write the objective function 
def obj(e, p):
    S = -1*entropy(p_vector(p + e), base = 2) 
    return S

##Constraints
cons = {'type': 'ineq',
       'fun': lambda e: -p - e + 1,
       'args': (p,)
       }

initial_guess = 0

result = minimize(obj, initial_guess, method = 'SLSQP', args = (0.5, ), constraints = cons)
print(result)
```

Comment: To pass `args` as tuples use `(p,)` and `(0.5,)`.  In some cases it may turn a scalar into a tuple for you, but just be safe I'd do that myself.

Comment: I tried it with 'args': (p,) when defining cons but I still have an error that says name 'p' is not defined in that line. Also, if it wasn't clear p = 0.5 is the case I'm trying to run

Comment: `args=(0.5,)` sets `p` within the calls made to `obj`.  But looking at `minimize` docs, it looks like `args` in `cons`, defines what's passed to the lambda.  So I'd try `'args': (0.5,)`.  I haven't used `cons` much, so am working entirely from the docs, not experience.

Comment: Hmm it now gives me a new error "<lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". I've attached my full code to the question for clarity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay, I figured that it's a mix of syntax errors on my part and how arguments should be passed. For those who may have the same question, I will post an answer here.

The objective function is `obj(e, p)`. We only want to minimize `e` so we create a tuple of the other arguments `arguments = (0.5,)`. That is, a specific value of `p=0.5` is set. Next define the constraint function

```
def prob_bound(e, p):
    return -e - p + 1
```

Now one writes the constraints dictionary to be

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq',
       'fun': prob_bound,
       'args': arguments       
       })
```

And finally, one calls the minimizer

```
result = minimize(obj, initial_guess, method = 'SLSQP', args = arguments, constraints = cons)
```

Comment: Hi @user1936752 , I have a problem that has constraints very similar to your constraint. I am trying to write down the constrain in the problem that I have explained here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72835244/2379433 in scipy. do you know how I can implement my constraint?